# google Adwords conversion script

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-ads-api

I have a form, that after submit the form I want to run the script of google Adwords conversion.

I'm using ajax and jQuery:

```
var dataString = 'name='+$('#name').val()+'&'+'phone='+$('#phone').val()+'&'+'mail='+$('#mail').val();
        $.ajax({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "newLead.php",  
          data: dataString,  
          success: function() {  
                alert('Send successfully');
                var google_conversion_id = myConversionId;
                    var google_conversion_language = "en";
                    var google_conversion_format = "3";
                    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
                    var google_conversion_label = "myConversionLabel";
                    var google_conversion_value = 0;
                    $.getScript("http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js");


          }  
        });
```

Everything works find, the alert message is jump, the script in newLead.php is working.
I just don't see the conversion in google adwords.

What can I do?

Of course I changed myConversionId and myConversionLabel to my real details.

Thanks

Comment: Found a page with what looks like the right answer: http://articles.adamwrobel.com/2010/12/23/trigger-adwords-conversion-on-javascript-event

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just send off the pixel request myself. Something like the following works for me:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
var goalId = 123456;
var randomNum = new Date().getMilliseconds();
var value = 100;
var label = "label";
var url = encodeURI(location.href);

var trackUrl = "http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/"+goalId+"/?random="+randomNum+"&value="+value+"&label="+label+"&guid=ON&script=0&url="+url;
img.src = trackUrl;
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

That at least registers the conversion, but I'm not sure if there are any issues becuase the actual tracking script isn't loaded.

Comment: It's working - just see that the var is trackUrl not trackingUrl

Comment: @EwanHeming +1 for your answer! I have asked a very similar question, would you mind looking? I think your answer is the same for mine, but I need to know a little about the variables. Which ones are required etc.. My question is located here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027246/google-adwords-conversion-services-issue-asynchronous-conversion-code Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the randomNum variable necessary? I don't find it in the original image url that is officially given by AdWords

Comment: It was there when I originally posted this, but it might have been removed now. Anyway, it's a good idea to use a random number as identical URLs can get cached in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but may be conversion script expects to see it's variables in Global scope.
In your code you define it in local scope - under callback

So instead of `var google_...` write `window.google_...`

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I think real conversion appears only after you actually use AdWords (click-through and make conversion) - so that is why you get conversions in AdWords based on number of clicks from AdWords and not from all the sources.

Does it make sense? :)

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at Event tracking, you can link custom events tracked from your website to your google analytics, then link everything together with adwords.

[Video by google](http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/v5/et_vpsv22_ad1_2/)

[Events tracking guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide)

Hope these links will help you out.

Comment: Event Tracking doesn't track conversions, nor will it send data to your Adwords account.